# How to get the Date value from HTML5 input type="date"

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, date

This is the user interface where user chooses the `fromdate` and `todate` from the form.

```html
<html>
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="searchdate2.php">


  <label> From date </label>

  <input type="date" name="fromdate" />

  <label> To date</label>

  <input type="date" name="todate" />

  <input type="submit" name="go" value="Search">


</form>
```

Then in searchdate2.php, I am trying to display the result with matching date range from mysql

```
include('connect-db.php');

   $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM treatmentdetail 
   WHERE nextdate BETWEEN '" . $_POST['fromdate'] . "' AND  '" . 
   $_POST['todate'] . "'");


 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo '<td width="100px">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td width="200px">' . $row['patientid'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td width="200px">' . $row['treatmentid'] . '</td>';

   }

  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
   ?>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get the Date value using HTML5 input type="date",

Can I do it in PHP or JQuery?

Comment: *"Can I do it in PHP or JQuery?"* Yes (well, PHP and JavaScript). You need to decide which one you want.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do it in PHP or JQuery?

In JavaScript, on the browser, you can get it from the [`valueAsDate` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-valueasdate):

```
// Without jQuery:
console.log(document.querySelector("input[name=fromdate]).valueAsDate);
// With jQuery:
console.log($("input[name=fromdate])[0].prop("valueAsDate"));
```

To access it from PHP, you'll need to submit the form and get the string value from `$_GET` or `$_POST` (as appropriate) and parse it.

Comment: As u can see from the code snippet, im trying to use $_POST to get the date value but fail, may i ask how to parse it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Should it be `console.log( $("input[name='fromdate']").eq(0).prop("valueAsDate") );` to have the date object (which I don't think is what OP needs...) from the input ? ;)

Answer (score 1):

[`BETWEEN`](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php) SQL operator works with numeric values... You are giving it strings.

I suggest you use the `>` and `<` operators, which works with strings:

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM treatmentdetail WHERE nextdate > '" . $_POST['fromdate'] . "' AND nextdate <  '" . $_POST['todate'] . "'");
```

---

**EDIT**

From your last comment (*«if i have 2017-7-1 in the db...»*), I think I caught your actual problem.
The HTML `<input type="date">` returns the leading zeros.

And the **leading zeros are missing** on month and date in your database.
You are a human, you don't need the leading zero to understand that "2017-7-1" is the same date as "2017-07-01".

But a machine doesn't agree on that.
To it, those aren't dates... Those are string. And the first is a greater value because `7` is greater than `0` at character position 5.

"abcde" is greater than "aaabc"
"12345" is greater than "11123".

See here:

```js
date_db = "2017-7-1";

date_post="2017-07-01";

greater = (date_db > date_post);
equal = (date_db == date_post);
smaller = (date_db < date_post);

console.log(greater);
console.log(equal);
console.log(smaller);
```

**I would fix my database data.**
You just need to clean it once to avoid some complicated scripts that you would need to walk around some malformed data.

Comment: I have tried using $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM treatmentdetail WHERE nextdate BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'"); as well as 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM treatmentdetail WHERE nextdate >= '$from' AND nextdate <= '$to'"); 
But i dont know why it cant select the from date

Comment: For instance, if i have 2017-7-1 in the db, when i pick that date in the date picker, the result wont show, Only if i pick ONE DAY BEFORE that date which is 2017-6-30, then it will work